# JSON Parsing issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am seeing a strange issue in Rails.

Request Body (request.body):

```
renewals[][driver_1][dl_number]=123&
renewals[][driver_1][expiration_date]=20130513&
renewals[][driver_1][last_name]=123&
renewals[][driver_1][state]=AL&
renewals[][driver_1][verified]=1&
renewals[][driver_2][verified]=0&
renewals[][id]=6415&
renewals[][insurance][expiration_date]=20130513&
renewals[][insurance][naic]=123&
renewals[][insurance][policy_number]=123&
renewals[][insurance][verified]=1&
renewals[][mailing_address][address_has_changed]=0&
renewals[][mailing_address][city]=GULF%20SHORES&
renewals[][mailing_address][state]=AL&
renewals[][mailing_address][street_address]=8094%20BEACH%20LANE&
renewals[][mailing_address][zip]=35023&
renewals[][driver_1][dl_number]=123&
renewals[][driver_1][last_name]=123&
renewals[][driver_1][state]=AL&
renewals[][driver_1][verified]=1&
renewals[][driver_2][verified]=0&
renewals[][id]=6412&
renewals[][insurance][expiration_date]=20130513&
renewals[][insurance][naic]=123&
renewals[][insurance][policy_number]=123&
renewals[][insurance][verified]=1&
renewals[][mailing_address][address_has_changed]=0&
renewals[][mailing_address][city]=HUEYTOWN&
renewals[][mailing_address][state]=AL&
renewals[][mailing_address][street_address]=123%20ANY%20LANE&
renewals[][mailing_address][zip]=35023&
renewals[][driver_1][dl_number]=123&
renewals[][driver_1][last_name]=123&
renewals[][driver_1][state]=AL&
renewals[][driver_1][verified]=1&
renewals[][driver_2][verified]=0&
renewals[][id]=6411&
renewals[][insurance][expiration_date]=20130513&
renewals[][insurance][naic]=123&
renewals[][insurance][policy_number]=123&
renewals[][insurance][verified]=1&
renewals[][mailing_address][address_has_changed]=0&
renewals[][mailing_address][city]=HUEYTOWN&
renewals[][mailing_address][state]=AL&
renewals[][mailing_address][street_address]=104%20MERRIMONT%20ROAD&
renewals[][mailing_address][zip]=35023&
```

JSON Parsed Params (params[:renewals]): https://gist.github.com/t2/5566652

Notice in the JSON that the driver_1 information is missing on the last record. Not sure why this is. The data is in the request. Any known bug I am missing? Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is just how Rails parses JSON like this (where your `[]` is massively nested). I've come up against this before - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#combining-them gave some explanation.

From what I remember, if you can put in numeric keys rather than just `[]` (i.e. `[1]` for the first one, `[2]` for the second etc.) then it will work as you want it to.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Not really possible when posting from iOS app that I can see yet. I will continue to dig.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I needed to set the `requestSerializationMIMEType` to `RKMIMETypeJSON`.

Comment: Cool - did that make it work how you wanted? What did the params look like?

Comment: Sure did. Your answer was correct in the case that I continue to use RestKit's `RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded`. When switching to `RKMIMETypeJSON` all objects are intact and the request data is properly formatted. It was very obvious when inspecting the request with [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com).